# javascript collapsible table without jquery

Tags: javascript, html-table

This is a simple question I can't seem to figure out and every google search returns a million ways to do this via jquery, but I'd prefer to use vanilla javascript because I am new to it and want to learn it well before using any libraries. What I am trying to do is have a button collapse part of a table when clicked and then show those hidden parts again when clicked again. Basically just toggling the display of a class of elements.

I have a button that calls the `test()` function
when clicked nothing on my table changes. Here is my javascript code. I am using `collapse[0]` because if I understand it correctly `collapse` is a nodeList and I always close and open all of these together so I only need to check the first element.

```
function test() {
    var collapse = document.getElementsByClassName("catOne");
    var i = 0;//Counter for loops

    if(collapse[0].style.display === "table-row"){
        for(i = 0; i < collapse.length; i += 1){
            collapse[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    if(collapse[0].style.display === "none"){
        for(i = 0; i < collapse.length; i += 1){
            collapse[i].style.display = "table-row";
        }
    }    
}
```

I've tested the function with this code:

```
function test() {
    var collapse = document.getElementsByClassName("catOne");
    var i = 0;//Counter for loops

    for (i = 0; i < collapse.length; i += 1) {
        collapse[i].style.display = "none";
    }
```

which works fine on collapsing the elements so evidentally the issue is with my if statement, but my IDE, Netbeans, doesn't throw any errors and as far as I can tell it should be working.

Thanks for the help.

Link to html and javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/ozjbekjy/

Comment: Netbeans is only going to tell you if the syntax you've used is parsable, not whether the logic is correct. That being said, if you can include an example of the markup you're using and better describe the behavior you're after, what it seems like you're trying to do isn't terribly difficult.

Comment: any chance you could create a jsfiddle of your javascript and html

Comment: @daniel here you go https://jsfiddle.net/ozjbekjy/

Comment: @TiesonT. I am trying to make it so I click a button and several row of a table collapse and then when the button is clicked again the table will re-display. Like jquery's toggle() see jsfiddle link I posted for the markup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect there are a few problems working against you.

First, you need to make sure the `test()` function is defined earlier in the page than it's being used. With jQuery, that means using the `$(function(){})` wrapper to apply event handlers on DOM ready. You can approximate the same thing yourself with [something like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9899701/534109).

Otherwise, simply place the `<script>` tag somewhere before the table (probably in the `<head>`), and the onclick will work.

You also are using `i += 1` where you could be using `i++` - they accomplish the same behavior.

Secondly, instead of manipulating the style attribute, use the [classList.toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods) function to simply add and remove a class that has the rule `display: none`, like so:

**CSS**

```
.hide-me {
  display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function test() {
  var collapse = document.getElementsByClassName("catOne");

  for (var i = 0; i < collapse.length; i++) {
    collapse[i].classList.toggle("hide-me");
  }
}
```

Your JSFiddle, with the suggested updates: https://jsfiddle.net/ozjbekjy/4/